# Hat problem, finding the probability of no events occuring

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There's this thing called the Hatcheck. It states that each person gets a hat, without replacement.

So the problem I have is this (problem 5B):

[image]

So I know the probability of event A, B, and C are all the same; 5! and the sample size is 7! since it's without replacement. I also know the chance of that occurring is 1/7!

However, I can't figure out how to even begin part B of the problem. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[21?????]$ Be the event that person one gets hat two and person two gets hat one and the other people get any permutation of the remaining hats. That is, it is event $A$.

You have determined that $\mathsf P(A) = \frac{5!}{7!}=\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(C)$ because of the $7!$ ways to permutate the hats, $5!$ are in the favoured arrangements.

Then $[215?3??]$ is $A\cap B$ and $[215634?]$ is $A\cap B\cap C$, and so likewise $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\frac{3!}{7!}=\mathsf P(A\cap C)=\mathsf P(B\cap C)$ and $\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac{1}{7!}$

Now to find $\mathsf P(\neg A\cap \neg B\cap \neg C)=1-\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C)$ use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

---

PS: Also, clearly if all three events occur, the seventh person surely gets their own hat. So $\mathsf P([??????7]\mid [215634?])= 1$

Comment: Can this also be right????
1- (A+B+C) - (A∩B) - (A∩C) - (B∩C) + (A∩B∩C) = 
1 - {[(5!+5!+5!) / 7!] - [(3! + 3! + 3!) / 7!] + (1/7!)} = .93 = 93%

Comment: Yes, thank yuo, @JMoravitz

Comment: did you get a chance to read my comment?

Comment: @Maru Yes, precisely